# OpenGL extension availability on newer contexts

Tags: opengl, language-lawyer

I need some clarification on OpenGL extension model.

For example, I use basic transform feedback functionality, which is core since 3.0, but may be available on earlier contexts via `EXT_transform_feedback`.

Does the specification guarantee that even a 4.6 context will expose `EXT_transform_feedback` in it's extension list? Or the extension may be omitted, as the functionality was added to core many versions ago?

In other words, is it sufficient to check `EXT_transform_feedback`, or I should also check if context > 3.0?

Comment: In my opinion it is sufficient to check the extension string but take in mind that some extensions move over time into `GL_ARB_` prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the specification guarantee that even a 4.6 context will expose EXT_transform_feedback in it's extension list?

No. The specification never guarantees that an implementation will implement *any* extension. Furthermore, EXT_transform_feedback isn't even the same functionality as the core version. They're very similar, but different (there is no core `glBindBufferOffsetEXT` equivalent, for example).

Comment: "The interaction with..."?

Comment: @genpfault: Yeah, I don't know where I was going with that sentence.